# hibernate validator failed to build due to java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, nosuchmethoderror, jakarta-migration

I was trying to upgrade quarkus from 1.x to 3.6.3

In 3.6.3 I have to introduce the dependency `'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-validator'` to support `jakarta.validation.constraints.*`.

Then I got this build error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.deployment.HibernateValidatorProcessor#beanValidationAnnotations threw an exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.getBuiltinConstraints()'
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.deployment.HibernateValidatorProcessor.beanValidationAnnotations(HibernateValidatorProcessor.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:638)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

In my API definition, I've noticed that the validations were applied to `@NotNull @Valid Set<Long> requestBody` (generated by OpenAPI). I am not sure the error means hibernate does not find any validator for `Set` class?

Comment: Are you sure you are mixing various versions of Hibernate Validator?

Comment: @geoand
you are right. There is a transitive dependency of Hibernate validator. After I exclude it from gradle build, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a transitive dependency of Hibernate validator. After I exclude it from gradle build, the problem is resolved.